# QGIS Modeler different results by calculate the $area

Tags: qgis, area, qgis-modeler

When I use the graphic modeler,add a field and calculate the area, the sum of the area of all records is different to result which I get by calculation in the fieldcalculator. The result in the fieldcalculator is valid. Alle shp-Files have the EPSG 31468

-->the results by Modeler sum: 10275 m²
[image]
[image]

-->the results by the fielcalculator sum: 10311 m²

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add more details: example, CRS info, test data, ...